# activating users via email

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http

Im interested in a way one service activate users. The scenario is that I filled form and sent it. Then there was a message that if I want to continue activation process I should check my email. In the email there was a message iwth activation link like: www.theservice.com

I wonder how they know that it was me :)

I know scenario in which link which is sent contains hash of users login or something so that server knows which user enters and activates that one.

Do you know how it can be done ?

EDIT:

According to answers: Strange thing is that I dont have a token in my link which I received. Link  is simply www.myservice.com and despite of that this service is still able to activate my account.

The only thinkg that I can imagine how it works is the cookie.

Comment: Does this service allow to fill form and send it on one machine and activate account from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail message may contain an html with form and a hidden field inside it for user id. When user click on the link form submitted on appropriated server where hidden field value retrieved for recognizing user id and following account activation.

```
function doSubmit() {
        document.forms["form1"].submit();
    }

<form id="form1" action="www.theservice.com" method="post">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSubmit()">Activate</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="userIdForActivating" value="userId" />
</form>
```

Comment: the only one solution connected wth my question

Answer (score 2):

you can generate a hash and store it in a database along with the user_id and send a email to the users email address with a link to your site and put something like &hash=yourHashHere in the url. On your site you check if the hash exists in the database if so, activate the user in the database. You could also add a timestamp so you can validate if the activation link already expired.

Answer (score 0):

what you do is create user activation token that is saved with user login details. Also you have there user email that is the token send to.
email in fact is something like

http://yourpage.com/activation/token

after in code where you have the link you will detect if token is present and if it is not you will promt user for it, usual combination is email and token

see more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx